# Which database design to choose for a survey app?

Tags: python, sql, django, database, django-models

I'm creating a survey app and I don't know how to design database. I need surveys with multiple questions and multiple types of questions.  There are 3 ways that I could think of:

a) Create a database table for surveys and every type of question and connect them with Survey_id column.

b) Create a database table for questions and surveys and have them stored in JSON like text field. Those Text fields could look like this:

```
{
    question: 'Who is the best student?'
    type: 'multiple-choices',
    choices: [
         'Bob',
         'Alice',
         'Alex',
    ],
}
```

c) Last option is to create a database table just for surveys and have them stored in JSON like format. Like this:

```
{
    heading: 'My survey'
    date: '2019-01-01',
    questions: [
         {...},
         {...},
         {...},
    ],
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Abstraction is important when designing databases and when its doable to just put all the data in JSON field in certain cases (say a payload from a endpoint), but if thats not the case theres defiantly ways to store the data in a much more uniform fashion.  Below is how I would start to design a survey app from a high level.

1)First you should defiantly have a survey table at the topmost level, so you can create multiple survey instances (say at different times or for different groups) that can contain different types of questions.  This would also contain the date, end time,  group etc...

2)Then for the next level I would create a generic question table. This would contain a foreign key to the survey and a char field for the question being asked.

3) Next I would then create a new table for each type of question you would like to support that inherits from the generic question table in part two so they grab the foreign key and question char field automatically.

3.1) Multiple Choice Example. To build upon this I would also create a multiple choice answer table as well. This simply would have a foreign key to the specify multiple choice question table and then a answer field for available choices on said question.  This would allow you to reuse multiple choice answers to select from.

4) Finally thats more setting up a survey to be taken not the answering side of the survey, another reason not to put everything in JSON ;) . For answering I would implement a SurveyResponse table at the top level and then another table that has a foreign key to SurveyResponse for every question in said survey from part 1.

Hope this helps with some direction.  Happy coding!

Comment: Up-voted as a good detailed response for your first ever answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about a database, then make it a database. That means normalised tables to store all your data. No question about this.